# Re-named associations working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have two types of users, one that can create movies and one that can create reviews:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :created_movies, foreign_key: 'creator_id', class_name: 'Movie'
  has_many :reviewed_movies, foreign_key: 'reviewer_id', :through => 'Review'
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :reviewer, class_name: 'User'
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Whenever I try to run the following in my users/show:

```
<% if @user.reviewed_movies.any? %>
```

I get this problem:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError at /users/1
Could not find the association "Review" in model User
```

I can see that I can successfully populate the reviewer_id with the correct user when the review is created when I go into the command line:

```
m = Movie.last

m.reviews[1]

# => <Review:0x007fdc4036a938> {
#      :id => 2,
#      :rating => 2,
#      :title => "bye",
#      :content => "byeeeee",
#      :created_at => Tue, 15 Sep 2015 19:20:25 UTC +00:00,
#      :updated_at => Tue, 15 Sep 2015 19:20:25 UTC +00:00,
#      :movie_id => 3,
#      :reviewer_id => 1
#    }
```

But I can't retrieve it from the other end. If anyone can provide some assistance it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError at /users/1 Could
>   not find the association "Review" in model User

The problem is here in this line

```
  has_many :reviewed_movies, foreign_key: 'reviewer_id', :through => 'Review'
```

Which should be

```
  has_many :reviewed_movies, foreign_key: 'reviewer_id', class_name: 'Review'
```

Comment: So I'm assuming that the foreign key must also sit in the Movie class, correct?

Comment: @Banner Updated the answer :)

Comment: def create
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
    @review = @movie.reviews.merge(current_user.reviewed_movies).create(review_params)  This is my code to create the review but now current_user is nil. I have current_user defined in my SessionsHelper so i'm not sure why it cant get the id. Any Idea? This is the error: undefined method `reviewed_movies' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your User model it has many reviews through which it has many movies called "reviewed_movies".

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :created_movies,
           foreign_key: :movie_id,
           class_name: 'Movie'
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :reviewed_movies,
           foreign_key: :movie_id,
           through: :reviews,
           class_name: 'Movie'
end
```

EDIT: The foreign key is there to tell your model which foreign key to use, if your relation isn't called the same as the foreign-key, so I think it should be 'movie_id'... Ok, not sure about this any longer, I guess it depends on your setup ^^